# inner space and orthogonality questions

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

i found this question that is made out of 2 claims and i've got to deicde if both wrong,correct or just one right. one of them i think i succeed solving, but i've had hard time with the other one for hours.

1)in $M _{nxn}^R, n>1, exists an non-zero symmetrical matrice that is orthogonal to every diagonal matrice.

2)let U be a subspace of $R^n$ that is defined as $U={(x_1,..,x_n) \in R^n | \sum _{i=1} ^n x_i=0}$ then the vector {(1,1,1,...,1) is a basis for $U^\bot$

i don't know how to solve the first one at all. regarding the second claim, it is true since an orthogonal basis can be made if $<v_i,v_j>$=1 if i=j and 0 if $i\neq j$, so {(1,1,1,..,1)} can be a basis for $U^\bot$.

thank you for helping me.

Comment: For 1) do you know the inner product for matrices? For 2) that is the definition of an orthonormal system, not the basis of the orthogonal complement. You can for example show that $(1,1,\dotsc,1)\in U^\bot$ and $\dim U^\bot = 1$.

Comment: regarding 1)no, this is a claim and i need to decide whether it's true or false. 2)so if we're speaking on basis for $U^\bot$, {(1,1,1...,1)} cannot be a basis for it? i think it can be, but if i'm wrong, just tell me